# drawLine won't show up

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hi I'm halfway through a simple GUI and can't seem to figure out why my drawLines etc are not drawing onto the page. I want to draw intersecting lines onto the DrawingPanel before adding a slider to adjust where the lines intersect, but can't seem to get them to show. I'm fairly new to java, and the code is not quite complete but any help would be appreciated! Thanks

### JPanel

```
package JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI Design");

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout (frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
frame.setLayout(layout); 

JPanel DrawingPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel ControlPanel = new JPanel();

ControlPanel.setBackground (Color.WHITE);
ControlPanel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (200, 500));
DrawingPanel.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (500, 500));
frame.setSize(700,500);

JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Quadrant");
JLabel label2 = new JLabel ("X: " + x + ", Y: " + y);
double x=0;
double y=0;

JSlider slide = new JSlider();
slide.setOrientation(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
slide.setMinimum(1);
slide.setMaximum(4);

ControlPanel.add (label1);
ControlPanel.add (slide);
ControlPanel.add (label2);

frame.getContentPane().add(DrawingPanel);
frame.getContentPane().add(ControlPanel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

### DrawingPanel

```
package DrawingPanel;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {


    public void paint (Graphics page) {
        super.paintComponent (page);
        page.drawLine(10, 10, 180, 300);

      //I have tried messing around with this but can't get it to draw. 
      //super.paintComponent also returns a 'cannot find symbol' error 
      //which i am confused about. Also the code is imcomplete

    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 4) **Don't use the name of a J2SE class for your custom class!**  At the very least, it is confusing to others.

Comment: Btw, I never see `new DrawingPanel()` in your code, so it's unlikely that it will ever work. But please follow @AndrewThompson 's advices. package name start with a lower-case letter (and is usually only lower-case letters), variables and methods start with a lower-case letter and use camelCase). Don't call `setPreferredSize()`: either override `getPreferredSize()` to return the appropriate value or better, use an appropriate `LayoutManager`

Comment: Override `paintComponent(...)`, not paint().